# Does Email Header record / include the IP address of the Receiver?

Tags: smtp-headers

In an email header, it seems only the IP addresses of the email sender and also the relaying servers are logged, as it travels to its destination. However, I need to also find the destination IP address for the receiver as well.

Is that not logged and included in the email header's information? Is the email receiver's IP address not recorded / included in the header?

If not, how can I find this information, if possible?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "receiver", you mean the user that viewed the mail, no this information is not available.

SMTP `Received` headers are added by SMTP servers along the way. Retrieving mail from a server via `IMAP` or another protocol is not an SMTP function and therefore, those clients will not append `Received` header information.

To get this information, you will need to check the logs of whatever [MDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent) was responsible for delivery to the user's mail client.

Comment: Thank you EEAA for this information. Do you know if OS X keeps logs such as these? I can't find any information online about it.

Comment: Well, OSX isn't a mail client, so I'd say probably not. You'd need to consult the logs for your mail client.

Comment: Hm, so would it then be OS X Mail? Or is an MDA an ISP? Not exactly sure what an MDA would be, and Google searching didn't really provide clear cut examples.

Comment: There's a link in my answer that explains.